# how to make a list builder with a row

Tags: flutter, dart

how do i create a list builder that's going to return a row like in the picture or a list builder that goes horizontal axis until it finds the end of the screen and then goes next line  [please see this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lQN5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a GridView.builder() to dynamically render as user scrolls.

Below example modified from this: https://www.kindacode.com/article/flutter-gridview-builder-example/

```
List<String> data = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];

return GridView.builder(
  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
      maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
      childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
      crossAxisSpacing: 20,
      mainAxisSpacing: 20),
  itemCount: data.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, index) {
        // Add your card/widget/grid element here
        return Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text(data[index]),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.amber,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out - it worked for me [image: image1]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(width: 15),
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Card(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(75.0),
                          child: Text(
                            '1',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Card(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(75.0),
                          child: Text(
                            '3',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Card(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(75.0),
                          child: Text(
                            '5',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 15),
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Card(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(75.0),
                          child: Text(
                            '2',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Card(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(75.0),
                          child: Text(
                            '4',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Card(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(75.0),
                          child: Text(
                            '6',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```